Making Mathview to work in Andriod studio
Writing a Java program that contains mathexpressions. Is it good enough to use MathView ? or are there more views or other ways to use mathexpressions in Andriod studio?
I am using the latest version of Android studio (Android Studio Jellyfish | 2023.3.1 Patch 1)
How to implement Mathview?
I tried the following with no success:
Adding dependency in build.gradle:
implementation 'io.github.kexanie.library:MathView:0.0.6'


 implementation 'io.github.kexanie:MathView:0.5.0'


get the following error:
Could not find io.github.kexanie.library:MathView:0.0.6.
Could not find io.github.kexanie:MathView:0.5.0.


Which gradle file did you add this dependency into? Project level or app level? Also this library has not been updated in over 9 years.

build.gradle (:app)

Take a look at this issue.

Are there any other Mathviews ? Are there other views that are suitable for Mathexpressions?

You can try this one.

no. get the same error: Could not find com.github.Nishant-Pathak:MathView:v1.1.
